# How can I fade out my overlay in Unity?

Tags: unity

Something that I can accomplish in 5 minutes in libGDX is taking me forever in Unity. I have a `Canvas` with a button that covers my entire screen. When the button is clicked, I want the button to fade out and then for the underlying UI to be clickable (if the button is just faded out but it's still on top, you can't click anything).

I tried to use `crossFadeAlpha` on the `Image` attached to the button, but the problem is that `crossFadeAlpha` is async, so I can't do `image.enabled = false;` when it finishes.

Is there *any* simple way to accomplish this task in Unity?

Comment: Honestly, I would get a tween engine like [DoTween](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27676). Makes things simple.

Comment: I've tried using a tween engine (iTween and LeanTween). Their documentation is lacking, and I can't find anything online about fading using either of them.

Comment: Try DoTween. Its is free and pretty easy to use. Syntax isn't what I'm used to (AS3's Tweener library), but I figured it out in about 20 minutes.

Comment: Guess you can fade the button right ? Why not disable the button when its alpha reaches 0 ?

Comment: @EmreE that's the problem. How do you execute a function when the alpha reaches 0, when crossFadeAlpha is an async operation.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Tween engine may not be necessary here, a simple coroutines will do the job :

```
private IEnumerator FadeOut( float duration )
{
    Image image = GetComponent<Image>();
    Color color = image.color;
    float startAlpha = color.alpha;
    float endAlpha = 0;

    for ( float t = 0 ; t < duration ; t += Time.deltaTime )
    {
         color.alpha = Mathf.SmoothStep ( startAlpha, endAlpha, t / duration ) ;
         image.color = color;
         yield return null;
    }
    color.alpha = endAlpha;
    image.color = color;
    image.enabled = false;
}

// ....

StartCoroutine ( FadeOut ( 5f ) ) ;
```

I'm on my phone, I haven't tested and the formatting is bad, sorry.

Comment: There's a slight delay between when the alpha fades to 0 and when the enablement is set to false. Is it possible to execute that transition more seamlessly?

Comment: Are you sure you run the coroutine only once ? I have forgotten one line in my answer. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. The update method of the button's script:

```
private float alpha;

void Update(){
    //Apply fade process here
    if(alpha <= 0){
        GetComponent<Button>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```